# Pandas: update a crosstab table from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, lookup

Source Dataframe:

```
            T1  V1  T2  V2  T3  V3
4/1/2023    A1  10  A4  8   A2  1
4/2/2023    A2  5   A3  10  A1  7
4/3/2023    A3  7   A1  1   A4  9
```

Target Dataframe:

```
            A3  A2  A4  A1
4/1/2023    0   1   8   10
4/2/2023    10  5   0   7
4/3/2023    7   0   9   1
```

I achieved the target dataframe through a loop:

```
for idx in df1.index:
    for col in df1.columns:
        lst = list(df.loc[idx].values)
        val = (lst[lst.index(col)+1] if col in lst else 0)
        df1.loc[idx, col] = val
```

Is there any better / direct method like `merge()` / `concat()` to accomplish this without the need to loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(names='Date'), ['T', 'V'], i='Date', j='var')
         .droplevel('var').set_index('T', append=True)['V']
         .unstack('T', fill_value=0).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Or using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d.values, index=d.index, columns=['T', 'V']) 
                  for _, d in df.groupby(df.columns.str[1:], axis=1)])
         .set_index('T', append=True)['V'].unstack('T', fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Output:

```
          A1  A2  A3  A4
4/1/2023  10   1   0   8
4/2/2023   7   5  10   0
4/3/2023   1   0   7   9
```

Comment: I liked pd.concat better as after reading the documents, it seems pd.wide_to_long is less flexible if the column names are not homogeneous. In the pd.concat method `df.columns.str[1:]` was mind blowing. You made my day, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help you. With `pd.concat` you have a loop at least a list comprehension.

Comment: Right. If I may ask, what would you have done if the columns names were random like 'A','B','C','D','E','F' instead of 'T1','V1', etc.?

Comment: And you want (A, B), (C, D), (E, F)? Use `df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 2, axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, same relationship (A,B) = (T1,V1) but you can't groupby 1,2,3 etc. through .str[1:].

Comment: I updated my above comment. Use `np.arange(...) // 2`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.crosstab function

```
pd.crosstab(index=yy.index,columns=yy.T1).rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None)
```